# Https Requests fail occasionally on Apple Systems, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, https, postman

The project has a https domain, and the Android app runs normally. However, the iOS app will get request fail occasionally. It also happens on Safari browser(both on iPhone and MacOS)when loading the web URL. Use Postman on Mac to test API of the project, the same thing occurs. And very occasionally, Postman shows that the TCP handshake time is unexpectedly long (20~30s, for example).
So, is there some problem in Server's setting, or some compatibility issue ?